# Cake PHP 2 isn't joining linked hasMany relationships

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to join all `AffiliateId` models for each user through the Cake PHP 2 query builder, I'm seeing my users through the following query, but I get no affiliates despite there being affiliates for some users. I don't want to join affiliates if there are none for a particular user, what am I missing?

```php
$users = $this->User->find('all', array(
        'joins' => array(
                array(
                        'table' => 'affiliate_ids',
                        'alias' => 'AffiliateId',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                'User.id = AffiliateId.user_id'
                        )
                )
        ),
        'order' => array(
                'User.username' => 'ASC'
        ),
        'recursive' => -1
));
```

Answer (score 0):

So, `joins` will just add a join to the query, it won't select the fields. You can use `fields` to select them.

However, using [Containable](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) and proper associations is the better solution, as it would nest them properly in the result and would also auto select the associated fields:

```php
$users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('AffiliateId'),
    'order' => array('User.username' => 'ASC'),
    'recursive' => -1
));
```

Comment: I've just given this a go, I get all my users, but no joined affiliate ids at all, `AffiliateId` is a `hasMany` relationship on my `User` model so if a user has affilaites by `user_id` on my `AffiliateId` model I should expect to see some results here but don't.

Comment: `'recursive' => -1` this is negating (or at least fighting-with) `contain` as that will [remove all associations](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive), removing that from the find call will likely meet your needs Ryan. 'The' Phally? it's been a while :)